# What's the difference between global var post and get_post?

Tags: wordpress

I use the_posts filter to add an object to each queried post. When access the added object, I get different result by using `$post` or `get_post`.
This is the code to attach the object to posts:

```
add_filter( 'the_posts', 'populate_posts_obj', 10,2 );
function populate_posts_obj( $posts, $query ){
  if ( !count( $posts ) ||  !isset($query->query['post_type']) )
    return $posts;
  if( in_array( $query->query['post_type'], get_valid_grade_types())){
      foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
         if (  $obj = new Gradebook( $post->ID ) )
            $post->gradebook = $obj;
      }
   }
  return $posts;
}
```

Then, access the obj via `$post`, sometimes get the obj, sometimes not (even when it's the same post):

```
function get_the_gradebook(){
  global $post;
  return isset($post->gradebook) ? $post->gradebook : null;
}
```

Access the obj via `get_post()`, always get the obj:

```
function get_the_gradebook(){
global $post;
  $p = get_post($post->ID);
  return isset($p->gradebook) ? $p->gradebook : null;
}
```

I can just use the `get_post()` version, but it would be useful if I know why the difference.

#### Additional info:

If you ask the reason I attach an obj to each post, I think WordPress may take care of the caching process at the first place. Then, other caching plugins can work on my obj as if working on standard WP posts.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about WordPress core concepts. Belongs at [wordpress.se].

Comment: $post is probably the database connection which is made global to allow it to be used from others function while get_post is a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets explain you with a little bit pseudo code. I am trying to be broad with my approach so that my answer is relevant to StackOverflow however I still don't know how many down votes I may be receiving for this.

The simple difference is `$post` is a variable and `get_post()` is a method that means you can expect a different output from `get_post()` due to several dependencies however `$post` will only change when you explicitly do that.

Lets assume something like this

```
function get_post() {
    return rand(0, 5);
}

$post = get_post(); /* lets assume random 
                       value that was generated 
                       this time was "2" */
```

Now each time you call `get_post()` its value be keep changing however the value of `$post` is always 2.

Coming back to the context of wordpress, $post is set using `get_post()` within the [Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) and corresponds to the object referring to default post ID for current URL where as `get_post()` will take post ID as an input and return the post object.

Answer (score 0):

$post is what WordPress considers to be the current "post" (post/page/custom post type) and can quite often end up giving you data you didn't quite expect. This is especially true if you perform WP_Query's in your template or have a template that uses data from several "posts".

By using `get_post()` with the ID you want the data from, you can be assured that you are getting the data you really want.